# Access the next page of list results in Reddit API

Tags: python, api, get, python-requests, reddit

I'm trying to play around with the API of Reddit, and I understand most of it, but I can't seem to figure out how to access the next page of results (since each page is 25 entries).

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get(r'https://www.reddit.com/r/Petscop/top.json?sort=top&show=all&t=all')

listing = r.json()

after = listing['data']['after']

data = listing['data']['children']

for entry in data:
    post = entry['data']
    print post['score']

query = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Petscop/top.json?after='+after
r = requests.get(query)

listing = r.json()

data = listing['data']['children']

for entry in data:
    post = entry['data']
    print post['score']
```

So I extract the after ID as `after`, and pass it into the next request. However, after the first 25 entries (the first page) the code returns just an empty list (`[]`). I tried changing the second query as:

```
r = requests.get(r'https://www.reddit.com/r/Petscop/top.json?after='+after)
```

And the result is the same. I also tried replacing "after" with "before", but the result was again the same.

Is there a better way to get the next page of results?

Also, what the heck is the `r` in the get argument? I copied it from an example, but I have no idea what it actually means. I ask because I don't know if it is necessary to access the next page, and if it is necessary, I don't know how to modify the query dynamically by adding `after` to it.

Comment: 1) You will be much happier if you use [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), as it handles these sorts of details automatically.  2) That r is defining [a raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2081640/120999).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`query = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Petscop/top.json?sort=top&show=all&t=all&after='+after`

or better:

`query = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/Petscop/top.json?sort=top&show=all&t=all&after={}'.format(after)`

As for `r` in strings you can omit it.

Comment: The first one didn't work for me, but the second one did

Comment: Glad, to know! The second one is more idiomatic, but also it seems to do some useful conversion on 'after'.